# Implement check wifi connection in react native using jobscheduler

Tags: android, react-native, android-jobscheduler

i currently working in an app that must check if the user is connected to certain wifi network, using JobScheduler i will able to achieve this but when phone is in doze mode the jobscheduler it doesn't work, and i need that the app(even if is in background or killed)check the connection.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is waking the phone up an option?

Comment: could be an option, any idea?

Comment: Maybe look at an Alarmmanager?